# Is there an error in the following function for matrix multiplication?

Tags: c, function, matrix

The following is a function that calculates the matrix multiplication between two matrices A and B and the value is to be stored in Matrix C. The number of rows in matrix B are the is the same as number of columns in A. I assume that there is an error in this function as it doesn't seem to produce correct output when the function is used, however the error may be in other parts of my program.

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
   int i,j,k;
        for(i=0;i<ARows;i++){
        for(j=0;j<ACols;j++){
            int sum = 0;
            for(k=0;k<BCols;k++){
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: The input matrices (which must be passed by reference somehow, since the size is not fixed) should be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

One I see is:

`int sum = 0;` should be done out of at least first `for` loop, as it is used in the outer loop. Your code will reset it to 0 in each iteration of inner loop.

Or better is,

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
   int i,j,k, sum;
        for(i=0;i<ARows;i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j=0;j<ACols;j++){
            for(k=0;k<BCols;k++){
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function should be :

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
  int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<ARows;i++){
    int sum = 0;
    for(j=0;j<ACols;j++){ 
        for(k=0;k<BCols;k++){
        sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }
    C[i][j] = sum;
    }
  }   
}
```

The sum must be reset to zero before each evaluation of the products of row and column elements of the two matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum=0` is doing sum equals to zero when evaluating multiplication and sum will only contain the multiplication of last value from first row of matrix(say M1) and last value of column of second matrix (say M2).
Hence sum will incorrect value each time correct will be:

```
void matMul(Matrix A, Matrix B, int ARows, int ACols, int BCols, Matrix C){
   int i,j,k, sum;
        for(i=0;i<ARows;i++){

        for(j=0;j<ACols;j++){
            for(k=0;k<BCols;k++){
            sum += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j] = sum;
        sum = 0;
        }
    }
```

}